# Detecting out-of-bounds slicing with tf.slice like in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, slice

In tensorflow, I'm trying to use tf.slice, but [as its documentation states](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/array_ops/slicing_and_joining), it requires the slice to fit in the input array. For instance, if you try to slice the first 5 positions of the tensor [1,2,3,4] it will crash. I want to have the same functionality we get with python lists or numpy arrays where slicing gets you the intersection of the original array and the slice you asked for. For instance if you ask for positions 2 to 6 of [1,2,3,4] you'll get [2,3,4].

How can I do that in tensorflow?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use tensorflow's python slicing operator, which is slightly more powerful than `tf.slice` and in particular does some bound checking to behave similarly to `numpy`.

```
x = tf.zeros((10,))
y = tf.slice(x, [5], [15])
print(y.shape)
# (15,)
z = x[5:42]
print(z.shape)
# (5,)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [tf.clip_by_value](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/clip_by_value):

```
def robust_slice( t, begin, size, name=None ):
    with tf.name_scope('robust_slice'):
        new_size = tf.clip_by_value(size + begin, clip_value_min = 0, clip_value_max = t.shape()) - begin
        return tf.slice(t, begin, new_size, name)
```

(not tested but somthing like that should do the job)

Comment: I've tried it, but it doesn't seem to work if part of the shape is unknown.